# Reading "a flat, binary array of 16-bit signed, little-endian (LSB) integers" from file in python

Tags: python, struct, binary

I'm trying to read a old file of snow data from [here](https://nsidc.org/data/nsidc-0271/versions/1), but I'm having a ton of trouble just opening a single file and getting data out. In the user guide, it says "Each monthly binary data file with the file extension ".NSIDC8" contains a flat, binary array of 16-bit signed, little-endian (LSB) integers, 721 columns by 721 rows (row-major order, i.e. the top row of the array comprises the first 721 values in the file, etc.)." The data is 20 to 50 years old so there's not much coding documentation

If I just open the file and run readlines, with this code:

```
with open(os.path.join(folder,file), 'rb') as f:
# contents = f.read()
lines = f.readlines()
```

I get something looking like this:
`\x00P\x00@\x00\x19\x00\x13\x00C\x00F\x00\x11\x00\r\x00:\x00.\x00\x02`

If I use np.load(), the results are number like: `-6.85682214e+304`

I imagine I need to use the struct package and the unstruct function, but I have no idea what format to use, and my attempts are not getting reasonable answers. For instance, I've tried just reading the first four bytes and using '<i' as the format, as shown in the code below

```
with open(os.path.join(folder,file), 'rb') as f:
print(struct.unpack('<i', f.read(4)))
```

And the print statement showed (-13041864,), which doesn't make sense. Any insights would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the data 16 bits at a time and specify this in your `unpack` format string. You're using `<i`, which wants 4 bytes. The data is in 16 bit numbers, which wants 2 bytes. Instead, use `<h`.

For example,

```py
# I chose a random file from their setup
with open("NL198303.v01.NSIDC8", "rb") as dfile:
    print(struct.unpack("<h", dfile.read(2)))
# prints -200, which is a "fixed value for corners" according to their docs
```

Here, `h` means "signed short".

I looked at several random locations in the file and only saw -200 and -250, corresponding to some sort of fixed boundary and ocean spots. Presumably there are other values somewhere, but I didn't look.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I'm just looking at the first file, which is probably just the ocean on the edge of the map. Out of curiosity, do you know how you would write this to return a list of the integers? A for loop reading the file, or can unstruct loop through an object?

Comment: Their documentation indicates that they have 721 rows of 721 values per file. So you could just replace the `print` above with an `append` to a list, 721 times 721 times. (Possibly discarding newlines after extracting the 721st value).

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your output to a bytes object (with `.encode()`) and then convert it to a list:

```py
dat = b'\x00P\x00@\x00\x19\x00\x13\x00C\x00F\x00\x11\x00\r\x00:\x00.\x00\x02'
lst = list(dat)

print(lst)
>>> [0, 80, 0, 64, 0, 25, 0, 19, 0, 67, 0, 70, 0, 17, 0, 13, 0, 58, 0, 46, 0, 2]
```

Comment: I think my output already is a bytes object, since I used 'rb' when opening the file, at least when I use f.read(). Then, when I use list(contents), I just get 56 and 255 repeating one after the other, which doesn't make any sense as the output

Comment: but I can see that you used the random string I put in the example, so I'll dig through my data more to see why my results are so weird